# Expected Type Error. Date format

Tags: java, hibernate, javafx, javafx-8

I've mapped VALUE_DATE field as follows:

```
@Column(name = "VALUE_DATE")
private Timestamp valueDate;
```

But when I binded it I've used

```
private ObjectProperty<LocalDate> dateFrom;
public ObjectProperty<LocalDate> dateFromProperty() {
        if(dateFrom == null){
            dateFrom = new SimpleObjectProperty<>();
        }
        return dateFrom;
    }
```

binding:

```
dp_date_from.valueProperty().bindBidirectional(model.dateFromProperty());
```

And then I use this date for filtering table

```
if (dateFrom != null) {
            sb.append("and a.valueDate > :dateFrom ");
        }
if (dateFrom != null) {
            q.setParameter("dateFrom", dateFrom);
        }
```

and I receive an error:

```
Parameter value [2014-07-09] did not match expected type [java.util.Date (n/a)]; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Parameter value [2014-07-09] did not match expected type [java.util.Date (n/a)]
```

Should I change `VALUE_DATE`format or something else? Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm done. Thanks to everybody. Problem is fixed by:

```
if (dateFrom != null) {
            Instant instant = dateFrom.atStartOfDay().atZone(ZoneId.systemDefault()).toInstant();
            Date dateFromParam = Date.from(instant);

            q.setParameter("dateFrom", dateFromParam);
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

On one side you have a `Timestamp`, on the other you have a `LocalDate`. It probably works if you have the same type on both sides.

Comment: When I set TimeStamp to LocalDate error is `[Assertion failed] - this argument is required; it must not be null`

Comment: Where do you get the first, and where do you get the second error? The second sounds like a completely different question to me.